# Is there a way to transfer more than one Pokemon at a time?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way to transfer more than one Pokemon at a time to the professor?  Or possibly an addon that gives me this ability?  Vendoring all the trash Pokemon for candies individually is really annoying and time consuming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the version [0.49.1 Andorid/1.19.1 iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-120616/), Niantic released the ability to transfer multiple Pokémon at once

> Trainers will be able to transfer multiple Pokémon at a time to Professor Willow. To use this function, press and hold on a Pokémon.

This also allows for transferring multiple different Pokémon. So you can transfer both Pidgeys and Weedles to receive the number of candies respectively.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Source: http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-120616/

Answer (score 16):

There is currently no way to transfer more than one Pokemon at a time to the professor.

This is probably intentional.  The support docs warn that once a Pokemon is transferred, there is no way to get it back.  The lack of this feature might be to prevent accidental bulk releasing of your Pokemon.

Comment: It may also be to create an incentive for people to spend real money to buy candies. Pokemon Go is a freemium game.

Comment: @bdsl I don't see where you can buy Pokemon candies in the store for coins.  Are you sure you can buy candies with in-app purchases?

Comment: You're right, you can't buy candies with coins, I hadn't noticed that. But you can buy other items which may substitute for candies in some cases, making it easier to catch or hatch Pokemon instead of evolving them.

Comment: @bdsl Can you give me an example of one of those other items?

Comment: Pokéballs, incense, egg incubator

Comment: @bdsl I don't see how those substitute for candies.

Comment: Because if you want a pokemon that can evolve from a different type, then you could either use candies to evolve it, or you could catch it. The first two items could help you catch it. I don't know for certain if you can hatch them from eggs.

Comment: Just the fact that the transfer is irreversible is not enough reason. On smartphone user interfaces, there are ways of selecting multiple files to delete, with extra confirmation screens. This is a solved problem from a UI standpoint.

Comment: @Nayuki Tell that to Niantic.

Comment: Having to go out and physically walk around to collect Pokémons could also be said to be really annoying and time consuming - the game isn't designed with efficiency as the primary goal. The only-one-at-a-time-with-a-warning method of recycling Pokémons is likely both intentional and the way it will stay, as it keeps people from making the occasional large rage-inducing mistakes that would inevitably happen.

Answer (score 2):

No. As of version 0.31.0 their is still no way to bulk transfer Pokemon. The reason is most likely to ensure you do not accidentally transfer a pokemon you do not want to get rid of.

They did make it easier with the new update. It takes one more button press, however, the slide down to the bottom and transfer was generally laggy. Especially for android users. They also got rid of the map showing where you caught the pokemon that would load last causing an even more troublesome time of getting rid of the pokemon.

Hoping that niantic does add some sort of bulk transfer feature in the near future.

Be careful when transfering though, some pokemon that have a lower starting CP can sometimes have a better move set. Maybe Niantic is trying to encourage the player to look at each Pokemon before ditching it.

Comment: That last remark is probably the real reason.